# Using the vertex density of the model loaded by OpenGL to find the bounding sphere of the model

Tags: c++, opencv

The vertex density may be represented by the triangular area constituted by the vertexes, what I am asking is how to use the vertex density to calculate the center of the bounding sphere.

Comment: "The vertex density may be represented by the triangular area constituted by the vertexes"... ummm, what? You lost me. Do you care to rephrase? (we are in the 3D context, otherwise "bounding sphere" doesn't make sense. But we have something about a triangular area in the premisses. What triangle?)

Comment: [Bounding sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere) - [Fischer's exact solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Fischer.27s_exact_solver) - has an OSS project [on GitHub](https://github.com/hbf/miniball)